# How do I update single hash value where key appears multiple times in ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, key, key-value

I have a nested hash I'm trying to sort by name .

```
pigeon_data = {
  :color => {
    :purple => ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky"],
    :grey => ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K"],
    :white => ["Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex"],
    :brown => ["Queenie", "Alex"]
```

so I'm looking for something like

```
 "Theo" => {
    :color => ["purple", "grey"],
    :gender => ["male"],
    :lives => ["Subway"]
  },
  "Peter Jr." => {
    :color => ["purple", "grey"],
    :gender => ["male"],
    :lives => ["Library"]
  },
```

But every time i try to change one of the values it ends up changes all the values with the same key.

```
{"Theo"=>
  {:color=>["purple", "grey"],
 "Peter Jr."=>
  {:color=>["purple", "grey"],
  ...
```

My codes a mess but here it is earlier
code already puts the seven birds into nested hash as the top level keys 
i think the problem is somewhere around here

```
def sort_birds(new_sort_1)
  new_sort_2 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(new_sort_1))
    new_sort_1.each do |ka,va|
      va.each do |kb,vb|
        vb.each do |kc,vc|
          #binding.pry
          if vc.include?("#{ka}") && new_sort_2[ka][kb].is_a?(Array)
            new_sort_2["#{ka}"][kb] << "#{kc}"
          elsif vc.include?("#{ka}")
            new_sort_2["#{ka}"][kb] = Array.new
            new_sort_2["#{ka}"][kb] << "#{kc}"
          else
```

Comment: Please give complete examples of before data and end data.

Comment: That Marshal shows up here with a dump-load is really peculiar. Are you just trying to make a deep clone of the structure? Also instead of `"#{ka}"` just do `ka`. There's no need for the extra quotes. If you want to stringify they keys, make it clear: `ka.to_s`.

Comment: Sorry it wouldn't let me submit more code than that `pigeon_data = {
  :color => {
    :purple => ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky"],
    :grey => ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K"],
    :white => ["Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex"],
    :brown => ["Queenie", "Alex"]
  },
  :gender => {
    :male => ["Alex", "Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Andrew", "Lucky"],
    :female => ["Queenie", "Ms. K"]
  },
  :lives => {
    "Subway" => ["Theo", "Queenie"],
    "Central Park" => ["Alex", "Ms. K", "Lucky"],
    "Library" => ["Peter Jr."],
    "City Hall" => ["Andrew"]
  }
}`

Comment: Looking to make all 7 bird names the top level hash that points to their color, gender, and lives

Comment: I have some suggestions for how your question could have been improved (but it's too late to change it now): 1) make all inputs in your example valid Ruby objects, in part so that readers can cut-and-paste without having to debug. `pigeon_data`, for example, is missing two right braces; 2) When you give an example *always* show the desired return value as a valid Ruby object. Here you show only a partial return value (for `'Theo'` and `'Peter Jr.'` only) and you introduce new elements that have come out of nowhere (`:gender` and `:lives`)...

Comment: ...Either modify `pigeon_data` to include those elements, add another hash with those elements that is to be merged into `pigeon_data` or remove the references to `:gender` and `:lives`. I suspect the last would be best, to keep the focus on the essential part of the problem; and 3) the colours are symbols in `pigeon_data` but are strings in the desired return value. Transforming a symbol to a string is trivial, so that's merely a distracting detail. It would have been better to have made the symbols strings.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)". We need to see a runnable minimal code example that demonstrates the problem, required input data and the expected output. Without that we're not working from the same set of requirements and can't provide concise accurate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll want to do is create an entirely new structure instead of trying to wrestle a copy of the existing structure into a whole new form. Ruby's all about transformations defined as a series of new objects as opposed to in-place modifications of the same object.

This can be illustrated like:

```
def repigeonize(data)
  # Create a target structure for this data that's a Hash with a default...
  result = Hash.new do |h,k|
    # ...inner hash that has...
    h[k] = Hash.new do |ih, ik|
      # ... arrays assigned by default to its keys.
      ih[ik] = [ ]
    end
  end

  # Iterate over the data starting at the top level where attributes...
  data.each do |attr, set|
    # ...have keys that represent values...
    set.each do |value, names|
      # ...and list the names of those with those properties.
      names.each do |name|
        result[name][attr] << value.to_s # Converted to a string.
      end
    end
  end

  # Pass the result back
  result
end
```

Where it works like this:

```
pigeon_data = {
  color: {
    purple: ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky"],
    grey: ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K"],
    white: ["Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex"],
    brown: ["Queenie", "Alex"]
  },
  lives: {
    library: ["Peter Jr."],
    cellar: ["Queenie","Alex"],
    attic: ["Lucky","Ms. K"]
  }
}

p repigeonize(pigeon_data)
# => {"Theo"=>{:color=>["purple", "grey"]}, "Peter Jr."=>{:color=>["purple", "grey"], :lives=>["library"]}, "Lucky"=>{:color=>["purple"], :lives=>["attic"]}, "Ms. K"=>{:color=>["grey", "white"], :lives=>["attic"]}, "Queenie"=>{:color=>["white", "brown"], :lives=>["cellar"]}, "Andrew"=>{:color=>["white"]}, "Alex"=>{:color=>["white", "brown"], :lives=>["cellar"]}}
```

Comment: this is perfect and thank you for the detailed explanation. Made me realize how far in the weeds i was with this and how hard i was making it for myself.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't just get every value for each attribute without checking to see if they already contain any of them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Is that asking "How do I avoid duplicates in the list?" or something else? The nice thing about the `Hash.new` block constructor is that it only happens *if and when a key is not populated* so the first time it creates the empty structure. The second time the structure is already there so it gets used.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind about Ruby is almost always the solutions to simple problems actually look simple. The code you have in your original example may have ended up working with a lot more sweat and effort, but visually it was fairly clear it wasn't on the right track. Instead of trying to hammer at a problem with force, try and think of your Ruby code as a series of smaller operations that chain together or nest neatly. Take advantage of things like how `if` actually returns a value to minimize how much code you have to write.

Comment: Yeah thats what I ment but now I understand better once you call it a block constructor. Obviously I'm just starting out but I have learned about block constructors before. I hadn't used them in ruby before this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Given the structure provided:

```
pigeon_data = { :color => { 
    :purple => ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Lucky"], 
    :grey => ["Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Ms. K"],   
    :white => ["Queenie", "Andrew", "Ms. K", "Alex"], 
    :brown => ["Queenie", "Alex"] }, 
  :gender => {  
    :male => ["Alex", "Theo", "Peter Jr.", "Andrew", "Lucky"], 
    :female => ["Queenie", "Ms. K"] }, 
  :lives => {  
    "Subway" => ["Theo", "Queenie"], 
    "Central Park" => ["Alex", "Ms. K", "Lucky"], 
    "Library" => ["Peter Jr."], 
    "City Hall" => ["Andrew"] } }
```

We can loop through the sets using a Hash that builds based on a default process.

```
builder = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = Hash.new {|h2,k2| h2[k2] = []}}
pigeon_data.each_with_object(builder) do |(category,values),cage| 
  values.each do |cat_value,birds| 
    birds.each do |bird|
      cage[bird][category] << cat_value
    end  
  end 
end
```

When the builder receives a new key it assigns a new Hash as the value. When this nested Hash receives a new key it assigns an empty Array as the value. So then we just place the items in the order we wish to have them appear `[bird][category] << value`

Resulting in:

```
    {"Theo"=>{
       :color=>[:purple, :grey], 
       :gender=>[:male], 
       :lives=>["Subway"]}, 
     "Peter Jr."=>{
       :color=>[:purple, :grey], 
       :gender=>[:male], 
       :lives=>["Library"]}, 
     "Lucky"=>{
       :color=>[:purple], 
       :gender=>[:male], 
       :lives=>["Central Park"]}, 
     "Ms. K"=>{
       :color=>[:grey, :white], 
       :gender=>[:female], 
       :lives=>["Central Park"]}, 
     "Queenie"=>{
       :color=>[:white, :brown], 
       :gender=>[:female], 
       :lives=>["Subway"]}, 
     "Andrew"=>{
       :color=>[:white], 
       :gender=>[:male], 
       :lives=>["City Hall"]}, 
     "Alex"=>{
       :color=>[:white, :brown],
       :gender=>[:male], 
       :lives=>["Central Park"]}}
```

Comment: This works but how might I go about grabbing and sorting all three values.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ color: pigeon_data[:color].flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }.
  each_with_object({}) { |(color,bird),h| (h[bird] ||= []) << color.to_s } }
  #=> {:color=>{"Theo"=>["purple", "grey"],
  #             "Peter Jr."=>["purple", "grey"],
  #             "Lucky"=>["purple"],
  #             "Ms. K"=>["grey, "white"],
  #             "Queenie"=>["white, "brown"],
  #             "Andrew"=>["white"],
  #             "Alex"=>["white", "brown"]}}
```

The steps are as follows:

```
a = pigeon_data[:color].flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }
  #=> [[:purple, "Theo"], [:purple, "Peter Jr."], [:purple, "Lucky"],
  #    [:grey, "Theo"], [:grey, "Peter Jr."], [:grey, "Ms. K"],
  #    [:white, "Queenie"], [:white, "Andrew"], [:white, "Ms. K"],
  #    [:white, "Alex"], [:brown, "Queenie"], [:brown, "Alex"]] 
b = a.each_with_object({}) { |(color,bird),h| (h[bird] ||= []) << color.to_s }
  #=> {"Theo"=>["purple", "grey"], "Peter Jr."=>["purple", "grey"],
  #    "Lucky"=>["purple"], "Ms. K"=>["grey", "white"], "Queenie"=>["white", "brown"],
  #    "Andrew"=>["white"], "Alex"=>["white", "brown"]} 
{ color: b }
  #=> <as above>
```

One could alternatively replace `each_with_object({})` with `each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] })` and `(h[bird] ||= [])` with `h[bird]`.

See [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-i-product).

Comment: Or we could go with `pigeon_data[:color].flat_map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }.group_by(&:pop).transform_values(&:flatten)`

Comment: @engineersmnky, true. I confess a stylistic bias for `each_with_object(<empty hash>)` over `group_by` when, as here, both get the job done.